# Attempted to read or write protected memory error, when i try to search in LDAP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ldap

i try to connect to an LDAP Server to read the contacts and save them into my table.

On some servers my code works but on on many other it doesn't. Im getting this error:
Attempted to read or write protected memory error

I don't know what the problem is.

here is my code i hope you can help me:

```
Protected Sub ADLoader()
    'Holt die Verbindungdaten aus dem web.config
    config = DirectCast(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapSettings"), NameValueCollection)
    Dim server, username, password, attrsAMAccountName, basisDN, filterAttr, attrNachname, attrVorname, attrEmail, attrTel, attrAbteilung, attrPlz, attrStadt, attrStrasse, attrTrigram, attrName As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    server = config.[Get]("server")
    username = config.[Get]("username")
    password = config.[Get]("password")
    basisDN = config.[Get]("basisDN")
    filterAttr = config.[Get]("filterAttr")
    attrNachname = config.[Get]("attrNachname")
    attrVorname = config.[Get]("attrVorname")
    attrEmail = config.[Get]("attrEmail")
    attrTel = config.[Get]("attrTel")
    attrAbteilung = config.[Get]("attrAbteilung")
    attrPlz = config.[Get]("attrPlz")
    attrStadt = config.[Get]("attrStadt")
    attrStrasse = config.[Get]("attrStrasse")
    attrTrigram = config.[Get]("attrTrigram")
    attrName = config.[Get]("attrName")
    attrsAMAccountName = config.[Get]("attrsAMAccountName")
    If CustomUser = "FIFA" Then
        attrsAMAccountName = config.[Get]("attrTrigram")
    End If
    Dim pfad As String = "LDAP://" + server + "/" + basisDN
    Dim filter As String = " (&(objectCategory=user)(" + filterAttr + "=*))"
    Dim results As SearchResultCollection = Nothing

    'Baut die Verbindung zum Active Directory auf und speichert die Daten in eine Liste
    Try
        Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry
        entry.Path = pfad
        entry.Username = username
        entry.Password = password
        entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None

        Dim mySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrNachname)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrVorname)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrEmail)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrTel)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrAbteilung)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrPlz)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrStadt)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrName)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrsAMAccountName)
        'mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(zusatzFeld)
        mySearcher.Filter = filter     ' Sucht nur in der Kategorie user und nur mit trigram
        mySearcher.Sort.PropertyName = attrNachname
        mySearcher.PageSize = 100
        Dim result As SearchResultCollection
        result = mySearcher.FindAll()     <<<<<<<<<<< HERE IS THE ERROR >>>>>>>
        log.Debug("AD Importer: Gefundene Personen im Active Directory = " + result.Count.ToString)
        Dim searchResult As SearchResult

        For Each searchResult In result
            Dim propcoll As ResultPropertyCollection = searchResult.Properties
            Dim ssoBenutzer As New BiObPerson
            For Each key As String In propcoll.PropertyNames
                If key = attrsAMAccountName Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.BenutzerName = values.ToString()
                        ssoBenutzer.UniqueName = ssoBenutzer.BenutzerName
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrAbteilung Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.Abteilung = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrNachname Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.Nn = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrVorname Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.Vn = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrEmail Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.Email = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrTel Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.Tel = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrStrasse Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.Streetaddress = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If
                If key = attrStadt Then
                    For Each values As Object In propcoll(key)
                        ssoBenutzer.StadtName = values.ToString()
                    Next
                End If

            Next
            i = 1 + i
            log.Debug("AD Importer: Folgende Person wird in die Datenbank hinzugefügt = " + ssoBenutzer.BenutzerName)
            CreateOrUpdateSSOUser(ssoBenutzer, username)

        Next
        Label1.Text = "(" & i & ")" & " Fertig. "
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("AD Importer: Fehlgeschlagen=" + ex.Message)
        log.Debug("AD Importer: Fehler bei der Verbindung zum AD Server" + ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to read users from servers that are not MS Active Directory?

Comment: no its from ms active directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my error.

i forgot to specify the property "attrName" in my web.config, it couldn't find the property and showed the error messeage.

now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The full detail of this exception is :

`Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Usually this happens when there is a memory leak in your code, but this could also be due to insufficient search permissions when executing the `result = mySearcher.FindAll()` line.

The servers you're trying to search through, do they all support logins via `AuthenticationTypes.None`? This forces a simple bind to occur, which may not be supported or desired for some directory instances. Since you're defining the `DirectoryEntry`'s `.Path` attribute, you may want to try `AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind` instead, as it's built for the way you're defining the `DirectoryEntry`.

Also, I *highly* recommend picking up a copy of Softerra's free [Ldap Browser 4.5](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm).

This would allow you to try manually connecting in and searching directories with different `AuthenticationTypes` defined - in the context of this question, I think it's just as important to define what's different about the servers that don't work, versus the ones that do work with your current code.

Comment: i found my error, but thanks anyway for your help. yes the ldap browser is a good tool to check the connection